# Running main project in Netbeans 7 with ivybeans

Tags: netbeans, ivy

I have configured my projects to use ivy in Netbeans 7.0.1 with ivybeans 1.1.3 plugin. If I open the main class and choose "*Run file (shift + F6)*" then the application starts without any problems. However, if I set the project as main try to "*Run Main Project (ctrl + shift + F11)*" then I get `ClassNotFoundException`.

What am I missing?

I have configured following scopes:

```
Scope         | Configurations
------------------------------
Compile       | compile
Processor     | compile
Runtime       | compile,runtime
Compile tests | compile,test
Run tests     | compile,runtime,test
```